# .NET SOAP Serializing Unbounded Sequence

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization, wsdl, service-reference

We have a WSDL which contains the following type definition:

```
...
<xsd:complexType name="OrderItem">
  <xsd:all>
    <xsd:element name="source" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="OrderItems">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="item" type="tns:OrderItem" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
...
```

When adding the service as a Service Reference in VS 2010, the `OrderItems` class contains an `item` property which is of type `OrderItem[]`. The SOAP request is then generated as follows:

```
...
<items>
  <OrderItem>
    <item>foo</item>
    <item>bar</item>
  </OrderItem>
</items>
...
```

Using the `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` attributes we can control the names of the `<OrderItem>` and `<item>` elements respectively, but can't get to the desired structure:

```
...
<items>
  <item>foo</item>
  <item>bar</item>
</items>
...
```

I'm aware that this problem could be avoided if the WSDL specified something like `<xsd:restriction base="soap-enc:Array">` rather than an unbounded sequence, but given the above is the only way forward to use some custom serialization?

**EDIT**: Example WSDL at https://gist.github.com/1422704

Comment: can you also post the definition of the element referenced in the output type of the message ?

Comment: Is it correct that you cannot change the web service and the wsdl and you are trying to shape the request XML via manipulating the XML-serialization attributes of the client-side classes?

Comment: Yeah, the WSDL is given, and we'd ideally like to use the Service Reference generated classes with some custom serialization to produce the required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that .NET WCF services do not play nice with our WSDL (which was manually created with a focus on the XSD and not on SOAP).

The easiest way to get the SOAP API to work with .NET was to alter the WSDL to use the SOAP array type, so `<items>` becomes a `soap-enc:Array` with `soap-enc:arrayType="tns:OrderItem[]"`.

The resulting XML generated by the Service Reference's auto-generated code is then correct.

Comment: @cubuckley
I am stuck on the similar problem working with .Net generated proxies. I got your idea but somehow I am unable to convert my element attribute under sequence to soap-enc:Array. Can you please share example of your final wsdl corresponding to the wsdl in your original question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @brain.overflow, I'll try and dig out the working WSDL and add it to the answer today.

Comment: @brain.overflow I can't be 100% sure that it's correct as I no longer have access to the original application, but I've [updated the gist](https://gist.github.com/cmbuckley/1422704) to contain the fix for the complexType as well as the new WSDL.